# Changing alt-tab cycle order, prefer fixed to recency-based

Tags: shortcut-keys

I would like <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to cycle through open applications in a fixed order (based on when first opened would be fine) rather than an order based on most recent application used.

Currently, the position of the applications in the selection display keeps changing, with the most recently used application being put in the left-most slot. Is there a way to prevent the order change? I'm spending a lot of time tabbing to the wrong application. It is distracting to have to look at this display to determine where the desired application has jumped to.

Is this configurable?